# Regex to determine if path is root directory

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am in iOS but pretty much any language will translate.

I am trying to write a regular expression to match a root directory:

ie:

First/  should match
First/file.txt should not match
First/next should not match
First/next/file.txt should not match

So I think the logic should be start at beginning of line match any character except "/" then match "/" only once and that one time should be at the end of the string.

I have:

```
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^\\/]*\\/$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    NSUInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:info.name options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive range:NSMakeRange(0, [info.name length])];
    if (matches > 0) {
      NSLog(@"match");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"not a match");
    }
```

But its not matching like it should.

Thinking

```
[^\\/]*
```

will match all characters that are not "/"

Then

```
\\/$
```

will match a "/" that is at the end of the string.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: you mean this `@"^[^\\/]*/[^\\/]*$"`

Comment: Thanks.  Just to clarify for my own understanding.  ^[^\\/]*  means start at beginning and match all characters except "/".  Then / matches one "/" then [^\\/]*$ which I am not exactly sure why you need this, but match any more characters not a "/" then end.  Would this do the same @"^[^\\/]*/$

Comment: Your's would match `foo/` but mine would match `foo/` , `foo/bar`

Comment: @lostintranslation To be clear, is your requirement that the string has one slash and that slash is the last character? If so, you don't need a regular expression for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression would be:

```
^[^/]*/$
```

This ensures the string ends with a slash and it can contain 0 or more non-slash characters before it.

Another solution (without regular expression) would be this:

```
NSString *name = ... // some path
if (name.length && [name rangeOfString:@"/"].location == name.length - 1) {
    // root directory
}
```

Comment: Is your second (non regex solution) faster, or "better" for any reason.  Also thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Regular expressions are generally slow and inefficient and tend to get overused. My second solution is much faster because it is specific to one task.